# Directories missing when connecting to EC2 via FTP client (Transmit)

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I successfully connected to my EC2 instance via Transmit (SFTP protocol, ec2-user and pem key). However, while I do have access to the instance after logging in I cannot see nor access any directories (only hidden files).

When I log into the instance from the terminal with ec2-user I, however, can navigate to /var/www/.

Any help to solve this would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I did it as I outline in [this blog post](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/aws-allow-ssh-sftp-access-server/). Basically I create a new user and grant that user permissions. I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but it works fine.

I've copied the important parts here, but the blog post has a few more images that might help.

**Create a user**

```
sudo su
sudo useradd fred
passwd fred
```

**Create some keys**

```
su fred
ssh-keygen -f rsa

mkdir .ssh

touch .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod go-w ~/
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

cat fred.pub >> /home/fred/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**Allow access**

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
PasswordAuthentication no
AllowUsers ec2-user fred
```

**Login**

Use @. In FileZilla I set it up like this.

[image: SFTP Login]